# Starting zsh is slow with Oh-My-Zsh enabled

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

Starting `zsh` with Oh-My-Zsh enabled takes ~0.5 seconds, which is becomes annoying when opening many new terminals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your `.zshrc` contains the following line multiple times:

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

I had two of those lines in my config. After removing one of those `zsh` starts 10x faster.

Answer (score 0):

My `zsh` startup was too slow; so I found myself putting a couple `echo`s in my config files to find out the reason.

I found out that the most delaying part was the auto update script. Just uncomment the `DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE=true` env variable inside your `.zshrc` file. I ended up with a 11x faster terminal startup!